# System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find table 0

Tags: asp.net

I got struck with this issue since long and am unable to find a solution
I have been getting this error:

> 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find table 0.' at line 3:

```
if (Session["value"] != null)
                {
                  **ds = proxy.GetId(Session["value "].ToString());**
                    if (ds!= null)
                    {
                        if (ds.Tables.Count == 0)
                        {
                            Response.Redirect("Timeout.aspx");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                            {
                                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    string Id = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["id"].ToString().Trim();
                                    if (Id.Trim() == "0")
                                    {
                                        Session["ID"] = "ID NOT CREATED";
                                        ds = proxy.Getid(Session["value "].ToString());
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Ideally there is only value getting returned from the stored proc,so the error should not occur in line 3, since I put all checks for dataset 'ds' in below code. Request to please help me ...

Comment: You want to check number of tables exists in dataset?

Comment: Here is am checking ' if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)' for tables in dataset

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked in the function GetId for possible causes for the error or if the session variable you're converting to a string has a value? I can see you getting that error if you're trying to turn a session var into a string when it hasn't been initialized.

Comment: Its already defined ,i didnt post u the entire code..but i think its not problem with Session["Name"] since am checking for not null only before ahead...

Comment: What is done with the variable ds (dataset) before you try to set the result of getId to ds? I don't think you have enough code here for someone to give you an answer to your problem.